# Jquery - Can able to run href in jquery method?

Tags: jquery

I would like to run the href from jquery method without click the anchor link.Please see the below...

```
<a id="excelExport" class="actionButton" alt="Export to Excel" title="Export to Excel" href="pexport" ></a>
```

I need to call the action class instead of above code..

```
function method()
{
    href="action"; // to action class...
}
```

Is there any similar function we can use in Jquery ?

Comment: Perhaps it's wise to start with the basics -> http://jquery.com/

Comment: Try plain old JavaScript: document.location.href="...". jQuery is not a magic bullet.

Comment: Or better window.location since document.location is deprecated and supposedly read-only

Comment: You want to run a method, without clicking an element? Okay, on what event do you want the method/function to be called? To do what?

Comment: @user2444474 did my answer work out for you?

Answer (score 2):

If I get you right, do you want something like this:

Plain Javascript

```
function method() {
  window.location.href = "action";
}
```

The jQuery counterpart would be:

```
function method() {
  $(location).attr('href', 'action');
}
```

Although I would stick with the old plain javascript method for compatibility reasons.

Comment: @rtpHarry thanks for the edit, I saw the error but thought i mantain the same syntax as the original post :)